# Chisel Concatenation Error

Tags: scala, vector, equality, chisel

```
class CC extends Module {
  val io = IO(new Bundle {
    val in1 = Input(Vec(5, UInt(3.W)))
    val in2 = Input(Vec(5, UInt(3.W)))
    val out = Output(Vec(9, UInt(3.W)))
  })

  val L = 5
  val ml = 4
  var y = 0


  for (i <- 0 until ml) {
    when (io.in2(i) === io.in1(L - ml + i))
      y = y + 1
  }

  when (y === ml) {
    io.out := Cat(io.in1(0) ,io.in2)
  }

  io.out := io.in1
}
```

This is the code for concatenating two strings after checking if they match or not. For example, if the in1 is 1001 and in2 is 0010, it has to concatenate and return 10010

Also, I have a couple of questions

1) Can we concatenate vectors?

2) Is '===' operator valid for vectors?

3) Can we compare two vectors?

The errors I get

1)

```
inferred type arguments [chisel3.core.Data] do not conform to method  apply's type parameter bounds [T <: chisel3.Bits] [error] io.out := Cat(io.in1(0) ,io.in2)
```

2)

```
value === is not a member of Int [error] when (y === ml)
```

3)

```
type mismatch; [error]  found   : chisel3.core.UInt [error]  required: T [error] io.out := Cat(io.in1(0) ,io.in2)
```

Can somebody guide me? Thank you!

Comment: Your question title is "concatenation error" can you give the error you get please ?

Comment: Your code can't compile as bundle input is 'i1' and you are using 'in1' in code...

Comment: Damn, but when I changed it to in1 in the bundle, it shows the same error

Answer (score 2):

Lots of confusion in this code.

First 'y' should be a Chisel register, not a scala Int variable.

```
val y = RegInit(0.asUInt(8.W))
```

Scala for loop is used as GENERATE in VHDL, it's for 'copying' some code line.

Then as I understand this loop :

```
for (i <- 0 until ml){
    when (io.in2(i) === io.in1(L.U - ml.U + i))
    y = y + 1
}
```

In fact the value 'y' should be a Vector :

```
val y = RegInit(VecInit(Seq.fill(m1)(0.asUInt(8.W))))
```

And your loop should look like this :

```
for (i <- 0 until ml){
    when (io.in2(i) === io.in1(L - ml + i)){
       y(i) := y(i) + 1.U
    }

    io.out(i) := 0.U
    when (y(i) === ml){
      io.out(i) := io.in2(i) 
    }
}
io.out(m1+1) := io.in1(0)
```

io.out **should be Vec size of 6** and not 9:

```
val out = Output(Vec(6, UInt(3.W)))
```

Comment: Thank you so much. But I am still finding errors 1) `value asUint is not a member of Int
[error] val y = RegInit(VecInit(Seq.fill(ml)(0.asUint(8.W))))`   and    2) `inferred type arguments [chisel3.core.Data] do not conform to method apply's type parameter bounds [T <: chisel3.Bits]
[error]       io.out := Cat(io.in1(0) ,io.in2)`

Comment: my mistake, it's asUInt()  (I in capital case)

Comment: I am still getting errors in the concatenation line `inferred type arguments [chisel3.core.Data] do not conform to method apply's type parameter bounds [T <: chisel3.Bits]
[error]       io.out := Cat(io.in1(0) ,io.in2)
[error]                 ^`

Comment: hmm, It's sound that Cat function does'nt return a Vec() but a  UInt: https://github.com/freechipsproject/chisel3/blob/master/src/main/scala/chisel3/util/Cat.scala   You should not return that way in fact. (I edited the response)

Comment: It still shows the same error `type arguments [chisel3.core.Data] do not conform to method apply's type parameter bounds [T <: chisel3.Bits]
[error]       io.out(i) := Cat(io.in1(0) ,io.in2)`

Comment: It's because Cat() return UInt() and not Vec(). You can't use Cat() to return the value.

Comment: Okay, what should I use then?

Comment: It depend of what do you want to do exactly.

Comment: I want to concatenate in1 and in2

Comment: I think you do not have to concatenate. I modified the code in my response to propose a solution.

Comment: Thanks, the code is getting compiled but shows error after elaboration. To sum it up `Errors: 1: in the following tutorials
Tutorial Compare1: exception  @[:@6.4] : [module Compare1]  Reference io is not fully initialized.
   : io.out[4] <= VOID`